# use javascript to create test checker

Tags: javascript, html

I am a maths teacher. I want to use my school's website to allow pupils to check whether they have the correct solutions to a set of test questions given separately on paper. I wanted to give pupils a textbox in which they can enter their solution and a button to press to check if it is correct. A correct answer will display a 'correct' icon next to the question etc. I am a complete beginner but I have so far managed:

```
<script>
function check(z)
{
var ans = new Array
ans[0]="522"
ans[1]="144"

if (document.getElementById('response'+z).value==ans[z])
{
document.getElementById('correct' + z).style.visibility='visible'
document.getElementById('incorrect' + z).style.visibility='hidden'
}
if (document.getElementById('response'+z).value!=ans[z] && document.getElementById('response'+z).value!='')
{
document.getElementById('correct' + z).style.visibility='hidden'
document.getElementById('incorrect' + z).style.visibility='visible'
}
if (document.getElementById('response'+z).value=='')
{
document.getElementById('correct' + z).style.visibility='hidden'
document.getElementById('incorrect' + z).style.visibility='hidden'
}
}
</script>

<img id="correct0"src="correct.jpg"style="visibility:hidden"/>
<img id="incorrect0"src="incorrect.jpg"style="visibility:hidden"/>
1a  
<textarea style="width: 100px; height: 20px;"id="response0"></textarea>
<button style="height: 20px"onclick="check(0)">check</button>
<br></br>

<img id="correct1"src="correct.jpg"style="visibility:hidden"/>
<img id="incorrect1"src="incorrect.jpg"style="visibility:hidden"/>
1b  
<textarea style="width: 100px; height: 20px;"id="response1"></textarea>
<button style="height: 20px"onclick="check(1)">check</button>
<br></br>
```

This works but is obviously very clunky (I have in fact used an Excel spreadsheet to generate the html code). My questions are: Can I use javascript itself to generate the textboxes and buttons? Can I obfuscate the correct answers (if a pupils knows how to view the source of my webpage, it's game over for my exam!).

Many thanks and best wishes,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, you'll generate and verify the solutions server-side. If that's not an option, drop a reference to a hashing library in your page and validate answers against cryptographic hashes:

https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/

You'll have to generate the hashes in your spreadsheet -- or in your own question-generation page using the same hashing library.

But beware! If there is a potential that your students are at all familiar with JavaScript, they could still easily open a JavaScript console and brute force it. Assuming reasonable answers tend to be numeric and below 1 million, it's pretty trivial ...

... One more caveat. If your answers are open text fields, you'll need to "normalize" the input before checking it. Remove extra spaces, punctuation, etc.

Comment: +1 hiding the logic on the server-side is the only 'real' solution.

Comment: +1 for the hashing, I like that idea, too bad brute force would be easy in this case with just numeric solutions (but I don't think his student's will be that clever) :D

Comment: I'm certainly not that clever! Thanks for you comments!

Answer (score 2):

Obfuscating in JavaScript is not really possible - there ARE obfuscators, but there are at the same time de-obfuscators (depending on your student's knowledge, this might be an alternative)

Edit: Here is an example of an obfuscator: http://www.daftlogic.com/projects-online-javascript-obfuscator.htm, and you can also take a look at Google closure: http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home for minifying and "kind-of-obfuscation"
But as I sad, pretty much anything can be reverted.

As far as generating the input-field and boxes ect, you should take a look at jQuery: http://jquery.com/ - it might be a little confusing in the beginning, but it is pretty easy and a BIG help with tasks like this.

If you get a little bit deeper into the topic you might want to consider server-side verification of the answers(so yout stundents can't read your code). It's not as hard as you might think, but for now jQuery should do the job.

I like your project though, I wish I had teachers like this back in the day :)

Comment: Thanks so much! For a start the daftlogic obfuscator is exactly what I was after.  I will look into the jquery stuff when I'm feeling brave! Thanks again!

Comment: But be aware the JS-code can be de-obfuscated with simple tools like this: http://jsbeautifier.org/ ;)

Comment: Thanks for that - I just tried jsbeautifier and the answers are still pretty mixed up, plus I would be surprised if the students have knowledge of such tools. Well worth knowing that the de-obfuscation is possible though!